# MPDF 8 ignoring font configuration

Tags: php, mpdf

Font configuration is completely ignored in MPDF 8.0:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['c', 'A4', '12', 'Helvetica', 25, 25, 25, 25]);
```

The PDF created doesn't have an **Helvetica** font or a **12 pt** font, as it should per the manual.

Whereas the following code works fine in MPDF 6.0:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4', '12', 'Helvetica', 25, 25, 25, 25);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mPDF since 7.0 is used **with config names as keys** in the constructor.

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'mode' => 'c', 
        'format' => 'A4', 
        'default_font_size' => '12', 
        'default_font' => 'Helvetica',
        'margin_left' => 25,
        'margin_top' => 25,
        'margin_right' => 25,
        'margin_bottom' => 25,
    ]);
```

see https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/construct.html